# Get Difference in Dates Over Time SQL/Excel

Tags: sql, excel

I am trying to get a date difference to determine cycle time of when something arrives to completion. However, I need the product to count towards cycle time average for all days it is here. So, something along the lines if arrivdate='8/16' but completiondate='8/24', I need for the cycle time for this product to be 1 on '8/17', 2 on '8/18', etc until it is 8 on '8/24' and then stops counting. I am willing to do it in either Excel or SQL, if there is a fast way to do it. Below is an example of the data in an Excel sheet[image]

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4xYGwf8uS7ZdE5YRDYzXzNuOTQ is a link to the file, as I'm not sure how to insert a table in here.

Comment: just subtract the arrival date from the depature date.  use int if their is time attached.

Comment: use `=istext(A1)` the cells with you dates and see if they return true or false.  If they return true you need to do some converting from text to date

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Does this suit?

[image]

If I understand your question properly this simple formula should work. You can replace the 0 with "" to leave it blank